# flutter firestore get all readable documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a way to only get the documents, which you are allowed to read with the [firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) plugin? I always get an exception when I try *getDocuments()* in a directory where I only have permission for a few documents.

Answer (score 2):

Security rules are all-or-nothing.  If the query you're performing requests all documents in a collection, but security rules prohibit access to any of them, then the entire query fails.  It's not possible to use security rules to filter certain documents from a client query.  The client must only construct a query for documents that security rules are known to allow.

Please read the section in the documentation about sec[urity rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).